# onclick blocks copy+paste on Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, mobile-safari

**Background:** I have a dropdown menu that basically works the same as the one described on [this other Mobile Safari Event Issue question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239270/mobile-safari-event-issue): click a menu item to display the dropdown, either click the menu item again or click anywhere else on the page to hide the menu. The jQuery that hides the dropdown is bound to the click event of a parent `<div>` spanning the entire window. This dropdown works A-OK in all browsers, including Mobile Safari, and I'm only describing it here for the sake of context.

**The problem:** this onclick event prevents users on Mobile Safari (tested on an iPod Touch 4.2.1 and iPad 4.3.5) from getting the normal touch-and-hold Copy | Paste popup anywhere on our site. D'oh! Based on my research, it seems that if an HTML element has a click handler defined, its contained content won't be copyable?

I've set up a stripped-down demo here (**Update:** I'm using straight JavaScript in this demo to illustrate that it's not a jQuery issue, but this fails to work with jQuery's .click() as well): http://adamnorwood.com/ios-copypaste.html

If you open that link in Mobile Safari, you shouldn't be able to copy the lorem ipsum text, but you will get a message via console.log() when you click on the text to prove that the click handler is firing.

Here's the gist of it, in case that link goes down:

```
<div id="content">Imagine a large block of text here...</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('content').onclick = function() { 
        console.log('You just clicked me!'); 
    }
</script>
```

**Things I've tried:**

- `-webkit-user-select: text` as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803770/unable-to-highlight-copy-text-in-iphone-safari-on-mobile-site)
- using onmouseup and other events instead of onclick (nope).
- moving the onclick to the `<body>` tag or to the window object
- Figure 6-4 in the [iOS Handling Events documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) is relevant, but didn't lead me to any great revelations about what to do...

Any thoughts? Is this the way it's supposed to work, or am I missing something? Is there a way to make this text selectable, yet still fire the click handler? Or maybe I should go back to the drawing board for how to best hide the dropdown menu so that I avoid this issue entirely?

Comment: This issue is particularly bad if you use event delegation.  If you were to, say, use jquery's $('body').delegate(".myclickable', "click", function () {...}), then no text on the entire page would be text-selectable in iOS.  My workaround was to inefficiently add click handlers to each and every link i cared about (also in a mixed text and link drop down menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, after putting this problem on the far back burner for a couple of weeks, a fix came to mind suddenly (at least this seems to work on first glance). Instead of using `.onclick()` (or jQuery's `.click()`) for this, Mobile Safari can make better use of the **`touchstart`** event handler:

```
<div id="content">Imagine a large block of text here...</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
        console.log('Yay, you clicked the text, and you can still copy-and-paste!');
    }, false);
</script>
```

With this code in place, the dropdown menu in my example case is able to be hidden by clicking anywhere else on the document, AND I can still get to the standard iOS Copy | Paste bubble when press-and-holding on the text (the desired normal behavior). Mobile Safari gets the 'touchstart' listener, other browsers get 'onclick'. I don't like having to put this kind of browser sniffing in place, but it solves the issue. Unless there's a reason that listening for this as a touchstart event is a problem, I'll flag this as answered.

Comment: This works, however the downside is that you will be closing the menu when users scroll on the page (maybe to access a part of your menu they can't see otherwise), or zoom in/out (perhaps to see better the rest of the menu). Ideally those gestures wouldn't cause the menu to be closed. This being said, I haven't found a better way to do it either.

Comment: Event 'mousedown' breaks copy/paste menu too. What is a replacement for it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery? jQuery seems to work for me on my websites in Mobile Safari.

Here's a jQuery code that you could try:

```
<div id="content">Imagine a large block of text here...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#content').click(function() { 
        console.log('You just clicked me!'); 
    });
</script>
```

Make sure you include the link to the jQuery file in your `<head></head>` tags if you haven't already.

Also I tried your example on my iPhone and you're right it doesn't copy it just highlights it when I hold my finger down on it:

[image: iPhone screenshot]

But, the jQuery way might work.

Comment: Thanks for testing it! I should have made it more clear that I've tested this with both jQuery's .click() as well as with the straight JavaScript (AFAIK those should work the same, anyhow) -- I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: No problem. It seems like the onclick is making it a clickable link for some reason. Maybe Mobile Safari thinks that when you add the onclick, it is supposed to be a link.