# Disable selection context menu in iOS safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webkit

I want to disable the default context menu that appears after a certain text is selected in iOS Safari (web browser). Is that possible?

[image: context menu destroy]

Comment: Do you mean in the Safari Web Browser or at a UIWebView within an app?

Comment: Web browser, edited question

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/z9ZNU/). Basically, the important part is to set the right css atributes:

```
body { -webkit-touch-callout: none !important; }
a { -webkit-user-select: none !important; }
```

Also, here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304012/preventing-default-context-menu-on-longpress-longclick-in-mobile-safari-ipad) which solves a similar issue

Comment: I've seen this solution, but it doesn't disable the text selection menu, only the long-press menu that appears when you long-press a link :(

Answer (score 2):

The only way i found was by removing the selection and select again with javascript.
Have a look at my code:

```
/* prevent ios edit-menu */
if (/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    !function(){
        var target = document.body; // the element where the edit menue should be disabled

        var preventSelRecursion;
        document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function(e){
            var S = getSelection();
            if (!S.rangeCount) return;
            if (S.isCollapsed) return;
            var r = S.getRangeAt(0);
            if (!target.contains(r.commonAncestorContainer)) return;
            if (preventSelRecursion) return;
            iosSelMenuPrevent();
        }, false);

        var iosSelMenuPrevent = debounce(function(){
            var S = getSelection();
            var r = S.getRangeAt(0);
            preventSelRecursion = true;
            S = getSelection();
            S.removeAllRanges();
            setTimeout(function(){ // make remove-add-selection removes the menu
                S.addRange(r);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    preventSelRecursion = false;
                });
            },4);
        },800); // if no selectionchange during 800ms : remove the menu

        /* helper-function */
        function debounce(fn, delay) {
            var timer = null;
            return function () {
                var context = this, args = arguments;
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    fn.apply(context, args);
                }, delay);
            };
        }
    }();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Hans Gustavson's answer, I propose a simpler solution in TypeScript:

```
function disableIosSafariCallout(this: Window, event: any) {
  const s = this.getSelection();
  if ((s?.rangeCount || 0) > 0) {
    const r = s?.getRangeAt(0);
    s?.removeAllRanges();
    setTimeout(() => {
      s?.addRange(r!);
    }, 50);
  }
}
document.ontouchend = disableIosSafariCallout.bind(window);
```

This solution is actually a workaround. When you select a text, you might still see the text selection callout shows and then disappear immediately. I am not sure whether Hans Gustavson's answer has the same defect...

Answer (score 0):

According to [onclick blocks copy+paste on Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032710/onclick-blocks-copypaste-on-mobile-safari), if the text is in an element that has an onclick event, the context menu won't be displayed.

Comment: Actually it won't even be selectable, which might not be what you wanted.